# Virtuals in mongoose, 'this' is empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

ok, i'm new to mongoose and trying to understand how to use virtual properties. this is a sample code that i've been testing.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var objSchema = new Schema({
  created: {type: Number, default: Date.now()},
});

objSchema.virtual('hour').get(()=>{
  //console.log(this);
  var d = new Date(this.created);
  return d.getHours();
});

var obj = mongoose.model('obj', objSchema);

var o = new obj();
o.toObject({virtuals: true});
console.log(o.created);
console.log(o.hour);
```

so i expect the log to be something like :

```
1457087841956
2
```

but the output is

```
1457087841956
NaN
```

and when i log 'this' at the beginning of the  virtual getter, it prints {}.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue is the `arrow function` used in `virtual` function, same issue could be found here [ES6 anonymous function and schema methods](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3695), the reason is the [Lexical this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) feature of `arrow function`

To solve it, please change your codes as below

```
objSchema.virtual('hour').get(function(){
    console.log(this.created);
    var d = new Date(this.created);
    return d.getHours();
});
```

Comment: thanks, couldn't figure that out my self in a million year :)

Comment: Is there an elegant way to avoid this problem all the while using `fat arrow` syntax? Thanks

Comment: same here, this saved me hours of debugging even being from 8 years ago

Comment: hours and hours of Debugging saved here... Thank you for asking the question, and for the answer!!!